# Facebook Like Button Behind Login Page

Tags: facebook

I'm using the standard Facebook like button from their developers page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

The only problem I'm having is that the page with the like button is on a page which requires the user to be logged in.

I've tried passing the variables to Facebook w/ the typical

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Test" />
```

When the like button is clicked, it shows up on facebook, but with the Title from the login page. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that Facebook's servers will try to fetch the page your user is liking but they don't have the session cookie for your server to consider the request to come from a logged in user. One solution is to put some token on the URL you are linking to. Ex: xxx.yyy.xxx/securepage?fb=123456

Going to the secure page check if user logged in OR fb=someexpected value.

Token could be: CurrentTime + HMAC signature with your private secret. When you check the fbtoken check it against your private secret and that it is not to old to let facebook in.